# limit $\lim_{t→0}\frac{\sin 3t}{\tan2t}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Evaluate the limit of:

$$\lim_{t→0}\frac{\sin 3t}{\tan2t}$$

I am struggling with this question. I have attempted it, but I keep getting stuck on the following step:

$$\lim_{t→0}⁡\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin3t \cos2t}{\sin t \cos t}$$

Comment: I followed the guidelines in my study guide for a similar equation. I'm not sure I did it right though...

Comment: Now the first equation has been fixed, it's OK.

Comment: @LHunt use l hopital rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the denominateur is $\tan 2t$. If I'm right, just use *equivalents*: near $0$, we have
$$\sin u\sim_0 u,\quad \tan u\sim_0 u,,$$
so that
$$\frac{\sin3x}{\tan2x}\sim_0\frac{3x}{2x}=\frac32.$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating, please?

Comment: Did you hear about *Asymptotic analysis*, and in particular about equivalence of functions near a point (or near infinity)?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of that. The textbook I'm using is very confusing, and I have a hard time understanding it. So it might be in there, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: Well it's rather simple in this case: $f\sim_0g$  means  $\lim_{x\to 0}f/g=1$. So the first equivalence is just a rewriting of a well-known high school limit, and the second follows at once. Now equivalence of functions is compatible with products and quotients; whence the equivalence with $3/2$. Final point (not explicited in my answer): a function is equivalent to a non-zero constant, means the function has limit at $0$ equal to this constant.

Comment: I see. Okay, thank you!

Comment: First time I see an accepted downvoted answer! :o)

Comment: I haven't downvoted but this is not a rigorous way to solve it.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek: I'm sorry, but this is a *perfectly* rigourous (and efficient) way to solve. $\sin u\sim_0 u$ doesn't mean ‘approximately equal to’  in an informal sense, as physicists do. It has a precise definition in *Asymptotic Analysis*, and allows you to get rid of irrelevant details in the calculation of limits.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $ \frac{\sin(3t)}{\tan(3t)}= \cos(3t)$

Comment: There was a typo in the question: the author meant $\tan(2t)$.

Comment: Sorry, made a typo in the equation...

Answer (score 2):

You started correctly. Now multiply both numerator and denominator by corresponding $t$s to get:
$$L=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin{3t}}{3t}\cdot \frac{2t}{\sin{2t}}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot \cos{2t}=1\cdot 1\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{3}{2}.$$
Note: It was used the remarkable limit: $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin{x}}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the identities (which should be fundamental)

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$$

The result should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $\sin 3t=\sin 2t \cos t+\cos 2t\sin t$ first

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to struggle

as f(0) gives you indeterminant form 0/0

l hospitals rule is valid 
so differentiating numerator w.r.t t and differenciating denominator w.r.t
you get 2cos2t/3(sec 3t)^2
substituting t=0 you get2/3

or else you can use expansion of sin and tan functions

Answer (score 0):

The given expression is equal to $$\dfrac{\sin t(3-4\sin^{2}t)}{\dfrac{2\sin t}{\cos t(1-\tan^{2}t)}}$$ which is same as $$\frac{\cos t(1-\tan^{2}t)(3-\sin^{2}t)} {2} $$ which tends to $3/2$ as $t\to 0$. Note that we have used the fact that $\sin t \to 0,\cos t\to 1,\tan t\to 0$ as $t\to 0$. These limits are on a simpler level than the famous limit $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\sin t} {t} =1$.